# Compact objects in category of schemes over a base scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

I'm wondering if the compact objects in $\textbf{Scheme}/X$ (schemes over $X$) are the quasi-compact morphisms with codomain $X$. By "compact object" I mean that the covariant representative functor $\textbf{Scheme}(X, -)$ commutes with filtered colimits.

If the compact objects aren't quasi-compact, what are they? Or, under what conditions does this statement hold?

Comment: Interesting question.  My intuition is that there should be no nontrivial compact objects, since they would probably be related to cocompact objects in a category of algebras, and nontrivial cocompact objects usually don't exist.  But it's not that simple, since the duality between schemes and rings does not preserve filtered colimits.  For that matter, I'm not sure that very many filtered colimits exist at all in the category of schemes.

Comment: Shouldn't the natural guess be that the compact objects are the schemes of finite type over $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not true that quasicompact morphisms are compact objects in general.  In fact, I suspect that the only compact object over any base $X$ is the empty scheme, and I can prove this in the case when $X$ is Spec of a field.  Let's start with a lemma.

> **Lemma**: Let $(A_i)$ be an inverse system of local rings, where the maps in the system are local homomorphisms.  Let $A=\varprojlim A_i$ be the inverse limit.  Then $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is the colimit of the direct system $(\operatorname{Spec} A_i)$ in the category of schemes.
>
> *Proof*: Let us write $Y_i=\operatorname{Spec}A_i$, with closed point $p_i\in Y_i$.  Let $S$ be any scheme and suppose we have compatible morphisms $f_i:Y_i\to S$ for each $i$.  We may assume the index set of our inverse system has a least element $0$.  Let $U=\operatorname{Spec}B\subseteq S$ be an affine open subscheme that contains $f_0(p_0)$.  Since every other point of $Y_0$ is a generalization of $p_0$, the entire image of $f_0$ is contained in $U$, and so $f_0$ is induced by a homomorphism $g_0:B\to A_0$.  Moreover, for any $i$, the map $Y_0\to Y_i$ in the inverse system sends $p_0$ to $p_i$, since it is induced by a local homomorphism.  It follows that for any $i$, $f_i$ is also induced by a homomorphism $g_i:B\to A_i$.  These homomorphisms $g_i$ then determine a unique homomorphism $g:B\to A$ and thus a morphism $f:\operatorname{Spec} A\to U\subseteq S$ compatible with the $f_i$.  Moreover, $A$ is also a local ring and the maps $A\to A_i$ are local homomorphisms (this is easy to check: the maximal ideal of $A$ is the inverse limit of the maximal ideals of the $A_i$), and it follows easily that this $f$ is the unique morphism $\operatorname{Spec} Y\to S$ compatible with the $f_i$.

Using this lemma, you can then find lots of examples of affine schemes that are not compact objects in the category of schemes.  Indeed, if $C$ is any ring with a homomorphism $A\to C$ which does not factor through $A_i$ for any $i$, then $\operatorname{Spec} C$ cannot be compact (it has a map to $\operatorname{Spec}A$ which does not factor through any $\operatorname{Spec} A_i$).  For an explicit example, you could let $k$ be a field and $A_n=k[x]/(x^n)$, so $A=k[[x]]$.  Then we conclude that for any ring $C$ with an injective homomorphism $k[[x]]\to C$, $\operatorname{Spec} C$ is not compact.

In particular, let's now consider schemes over a field $k$.  Let $Z$ be any nonempty scheme over $X=\operatorname{Spec} k$, and let $T$ be a set of cardinality greater than that of the residue field of some point $p\in Z$.  For each cofinite subset $I\subseteq T$, consider the field $k(I)$ of rational functions over $k$ with a variable for each element of $I$.  These fields form an inverse system of subfields of $k(T)$, and their inverse limit (i.e., intersection) is just $k$.  Thus by the Lemma, the schemes $\operatorname{Spec} k(I)$ form a directed system with colimit $X$.  Now $Z$ has a morphism to $X$, but it does not have a morphism to $\operatorname{Spec} k(I)$ for any $I$, since the residue field of $Z$ at the point $p$ has cardinality smaller than that of $k(I)$.  Thus $Z$ is not compact in the category of schemes over $X$.